# Jquery Dialog pop up doesn't work with window.showModalDialog(..)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page that i call in a web browser's new tab. This page basically
 make use of jquery dialog pop up - That is, on this page there is a grid filled with data,
so as soon as the user clicks on one of the rows then jquery dialog pop up shows up to allow the 
user to edit the data for this particular row. It saves the data by calling server side '[Webmethod]' -> ajax/json .

Everything works fine if i open this page in browser's new tab. But the problem i'm having is that
 this pop up fails to call server side '[WebMethod]' if i open the page in Webpage Dialog (window.showModalDialog) .

Does anybody know why ?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using that does not work..

Comment: The code is too long, and im not allowed to type more than 585 characters on stackoverflow.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Does Jquery Dialog pop up support window.showModalDialog() ? Can i use ajax/json in window.showModalDialog() ?